# Linux SSTP VPN connection appears successful but then hangs

Tags: linux, networking, vpn

I am attempting to connect to a VPN with a Linux Debian machine using SSTP. The connection appears successful but then I am unable to connect to either resources behind the VPN or the internet. I believe I might have routing rules wrong somehow but I am out of my depth and trying different options has so far not yielded a working solution.

The command I am using to connect to the VPN is:

`sudo /usr/sbin/sstpc --log-stderr --cert-warn --user USER --password PASSWORD vpn.WEBSITE.com usepeerdns require-mschap-v2 noauth noipdefault nodefaultroute refuse-eap noccp --log-level 5`

(I've replaced my credentials above and inside the below logs, as well as the specific VPN IP address I'm trying to connect to.) That command results in the following output being logged:

```
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: Resolved vpn.WEBSITE.com to a.b.c.d
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: Connected to vpn.WEBSITE.com
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: Sending Connect-Request Message
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP CRTL PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   TYPE(1): CONNECT REQUEST, ATTR(1):
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:     ENCAP PROTO(1): 6
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP CRTL PKT(48)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   TYPE(2): CONNECT ACK, ATTR(1):
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:     CRYPTO BIND REQ(4): 40
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: Started PPP Link Negotiation
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(28)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 1  CONFREQ ASYNCMAP: 00 00 00 00 MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(60)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 0  CONFREQ MRU: 4091 AUTH: PAP MAGIC: 0x40311748 CALLBACK: 06 MRRU: 1614 EPDISC: 01 E8 61 37 D2 2E EB 4E C4 BF 67 15 80 86 C0 8F 21 00 00 00 00
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(28)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 1  CONFACK ASYNCMAP: 00 00 00 00 MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(19)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 0  CONFREJ CALLBACK: 06 MRRU: 1614
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(53)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 1  CONFREQ MRU: 4091 AUTH: PAP MAGIC: 0x40311748 EPDISC: 01 E8 61 37 D2 2E EB 4E C4 BF 67 15 80 86 C0 8F 21 00 00 00 00
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(53)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 1  CONFACK MRU: 4091 AUTH: PAP MAGIC: 0x40311748 EPDISC: 01 E8 61 37 D2 2E EB 4E C4 BF 67 15 80 86 C0 8F 21 00 00 00 00
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 0  ECHOREQ MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(40)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP PAP ID: 1  CONFREQ NAME="USER", PASSWORD: "PASSWORD"
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:06:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 0  ECHOREP MAGIC: 0x40311748
Oct 27 11:06:38 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(40)
Oct 27 11:06:38 sstpc[245506]:   PPP PAP ID: 2  CONFREQ NAME="USER", PASSWORD: "PASSWORD"
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(37)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP PAP ID: 2  CONFACK RESULT="Success. Logging you in..."
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: Sending Connected Message
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP CRTL PKT(112)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   TYPE(4): CONNECTED, ATTR(1):
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:     CRYPTO BIND(3): 104
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: Connection Established
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(34)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 1  CONFREQ COMPRESSTYPE: VJ [0x0F 0x01] ADDR: 0.0.0.0 MS_DNS1: 0.0.0.0 MS_DNS2: 0.0.0.0
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(20)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(16)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP CCP ID: 3  CONFREQ MPPC [ +H -M -S -L -D +C ]
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(16)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 4  CONFREQ ADDR: 10.60.20.252
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(22)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 2  PROTOREJ CCP
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(16)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 4  CONFACK ADDR: 10.60.20.252
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(16)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 1  CONFREJ COMPRESSTYPE: VJ [0x0F 0x01]
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(26)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 5  PROTOREJ 80570073
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(28)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 2  CONFREQ ADDR: 0.0.0.0 MS_DNS1: 0.0.0.0 MS_DNS2: 0.0.0.0
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(28)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 2  CONFNAK ADDR: 10.60.20.74 MS_DNS1: 10.60.20.10 MS_DNS2: 10.60.20.15
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(28)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 3  CONFREQ ADDR: 10.60.20.74 MS_DNS1: 10.60.20.10 MS_DNS2: 10.60.20.15
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(28)
Oct 27 11:06:41 sstpc[245506]:   PPP IPCP ID: 3  CONFACK ADDR: 10.60.20.74 MS_DNS1: 10.60.20.10 MS_DNS2: 10.60.20.15
Oct 27 11:07:05 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:07:05 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 1  ECHOREQ MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
Oct 27 11:07:05 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:07:05 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 1  ECHOREP MAGIC: 0x40311748
Oct 27 11:07:31 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(333)
Oct 27 11:07:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:07:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 2  ECHOREQ MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
Oct 27 11:07:35 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:07:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 2  ECHOREP MAGIC: 0x40311748
Oct 27 11:08:05 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:08:05 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 3  ECHOREQ MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
Oct 27 11:08:05 sstpc[245506]: RECV SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:08:05 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 3  ECHOREP MAGIC: 0x40311748
Oct 27 11:08:35 sstpc[245506]: SEND SSTP DATA PKT(14)
Oct 27 11:08:35 sstpc[245506]:   PPP LCP ID: 4  ECHOREQ MAGIC: 0x7764C36E
...
```

I am pretty positive I've successfully connected to the VPN for a couple of reasons:

1. I get a Duo Mobile push notification on my phone which was set up by my company and is required to connect.
2. I can ping either the vpn.WEBSITE.com IP address a.b.x.y or the internal VPN server address at 10.60.20.252 and I will get packets back.
3. When comparing VPN details and properties with my Windows machine which has the VPN set up and working, all the IP and DNS addresses match up.

However when I try to ping google.com or access resources behind the VPN, specifically a git repo located at gitlab.WEBSITE.net, the terminal just hangs and nothing happens (no output appears in the terminal from the logging).

With all of this I think it's most likely that my routing table is somehow off, though I'm not sure what. The route table looks like this (gotten using `ip route show`):

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev enp4s0
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp4s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.246 
10.60.20.252 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.60.20.78 
a.b.c.d via 10.0.0.1 dev enp4s0 src 10.0.0.246
```

The last route I added to the table via a `--save-server-route` argument inside one of the many `sstpc` commands I've run.

Please let me know if you see anything off in the route table or anywhere else, and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

After working with an IT person in my company I was able to solve this. The VPN was connected but my routes weren't set such that I had access to the networks on the other side of the VPN. Still don't fully understand everything but once I ran the following command to add the networks on the other side, then I was able to access the internal resources as well as the internet:

`sudo -- ip r add 10.60.0.0/16 via a.b.c.d dev ppp0`

This command needs to be run every time the VPN is connected.